# WordPress admin-ajax returns "0" on the Viewer-Facing Side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm pretty new in Wordpress plugins, so I have a question for you guys. I have a problem with admin-ajax call on the viewer-facing side of site. I'm using shortcodes in wordpress posts, to make a link, which must call ajax action. Unfortunately admin-ajax.php returns 0 every single time. Take a look on my code and maybe you can help me to discover what i'm doing wrong.

PHP side:

```
class myClass {

    public function __construct() {
        if (defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_myAction', array($this, 'myCallback') );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myAction', array($this, 'myCallback') );
        }
    }

    public function myCallback() {
        echo "test";
        die();
    }
}
```

and there is Ajax call in Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var link = $('a.myLink');
    link.on('click', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/myapp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'myAction',
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });   
    });
});
```

Do you have some ideas why that code isn't working and admin-ajax.php returns "0"?

Comment: What are you expecting as an output?

Comment: @Nikos that code should output "test" on console, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. a) You are never running the `download_file()` , b) I think the `die()` would not allow the output, and c) you are not instantiating the class

Comment: @Nikos sorry, just edited download_file() to myCallback(), my mistake. Without die() still doesn't work. As I know myCallback() function isn't even called. Just like ajax-admin.php doesn't call do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] )

Comment: I see. I am afraid I don't have any more suggestions. Perhaps you could add `echo` in every step that should have happened and see the output( perhaps write to a file?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Two things:

```
data: 'myAction'
```

replaced by

```
data: {
    action: 'myAction'
}
```

and in main plugin file I had

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    // there should be new myClass() too
} else {
    $class = new myClass();
}
```

thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ajax call in this format :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var link = $('a.myLink');
    link.on('click', function(e) {
       var details = {
            'action': 'myAction'
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/myapp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: details,  // data format
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });   
    });
});
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try with Enque [**JQuery Form Plugin**](http://jquery.malsup.com/form) Before Your Ajax request.

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','include_jquery_form_plugin');
function include_jquery_form_plugin(){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-form',array('jquery'),false,true ); 
}
```